# Indexing hyphen based on space in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on indexing data based on special character such as hyphen.
I have to index hyphen when there is no space around it and not index it when there is space around it.For example:
To be Indexed : Lease-Rent as lease, -,rent, lease-rent
To not be Indexed :Lease - Rent as lease,rent
My settings is:

```
{
   "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "indexAnalyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "indexTokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "indexTokenizer": {
          "type": "simple_pattern",
          "pattern": "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([-]+)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do i have to do this?